# A program that prints the number of times a string occurs(Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's the code I wrote to find the number of times the word "bob" repeats in the word.

```
word= 'azcbobobegghakl'

count =0

num=0

for nxt in word:

    count += 1

    if nxt =="b":

        bb= word[count-1:]

        num += bb.count("bob")

    else:

        break

print("number=" + str(num))
```

It's giving me number=0 everytime.

Comment: remove the `else` branch - it `breaks` on the very first letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What happened is:**
You check if `nxt` is equal to "b", that's not the case for the first letter being "a".

Thus it executes the `else` part which **immediately** brakes the loop and continues with the `print` statement, which prints 0 because it never got past the first character.

**Simply removing the `else` part fixes this**

```
word= 'azcbobobegghakl'
count =0
num=0

for nxt in word:

    count += 1

    if nxt =="b":
        bb= word[count-1:]
        num += bb.count("bob")

print("number=" + str(num))
```

Output: `number=2`

Answer (score 0):

Consider what happens if nxt is not b. Else breaks the cycle. That means that right now you only check of the word itself starts with b.

Also using count() you will count the same substring more then once.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be confused between **continue** and **break**. There is not need to use break, even you can drop the entire else part. But if you don't wanna drop it, then use *continue* in place of *break*.

**break** : break from the loop and execute the statement written just after the looping statement(ie,statement outside the loop)

**continue** : continue makes the compiler/interpreter to skip the entire piece of code written after the continue statement(within the loop) and move to the next iteration(in simple words, move to next index of list).

```
word= 'azcbobobegghakl'

count =0

num=0

for nxt in word:

    count += 1

    if nxt =="b":

        bb= word[count-1:]

        num += bb.count("bob")

    else:
        continue

print("number=" + str(num))
```

You can also use the regex library method as:

```
import re

word= 'azcbobobegghakl'
count = 0
pattern_to_match = 'bob'

for match in re.findall(pattern_to_match,word):
    count +=1

print("Match Count : %s" % count)
```